# java socket download image

Tags: java, sockets, binary

I have done some research, also checked answer on stackoverflow. However i just cant get my code right, please help. the code can run, but i cant get the image, it shows 0kb.

```
Socket socket = new Socket(addr, port);  


byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];



PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);


writer.println("GET " + url.getFile() + " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
writer.println("HOST:" + url.getHost() + "\r\n");
writer.println("\r\n");


DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


int n = 0;
while (-1!=(n=in.read(buffer)))
{
     out.write(buffer, 0, n);
}
out.close();
in.close();
byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("0.jpeg");
fos.write(response);
fos.close();
}catch (Exception e){
     System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: @PrimosK: please read the homework tag wiki

Answer (score 2):

Using raw sockets to perform an HTTP GET is much more complicated than necessary.
I recommend using an HTTP client like the one from Apache or you can use java.net.URLConnection.  See [How do I do a HTTP GET in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485708/how-do-i-do-a-http-get-in-java) or [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: thanks, this is my homework, only can use socket. i dont have many choice to use url connection.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have any obvious flaws. If you're getting a zero length file, it's because you aren't sending anything.

BTW you don't need the `ByteArrayOutputStream.` You can write everything you read directly to the `FileOutputStream.` Saves both time and space.