# Storing an HTML page in a string

Tags: java, html

I have a URL, from which I need its HTML. I used the following piece of code.

```
String url = "http://www.sears.com/search="+keywords;
String jsp = retrieveContent(url);
```

I noticed that the string `jsp` has different contents than the actual source code of the web page (when I view source from my browser). I believe a server-side script (or it is being redirected) is being called when the browser opens and this  script's output is what i see. Can you tell me a way to get the actual html file of the page?

You can check this link as an example. how do i get the actual html of this pagE?

http://www.sears.com/search=baby%20strollers

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSP.  It probably sends different responses to different User-Agents.

Comment: try using an http get on that url. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485708/how-do-i-do-a-http-get-in-java

Comment: I'll put it a little more clearly. I need to get a html file from a url in java, but when i do it, it shows a different source code rather than the actual source code, do you have any idea how to get the actual source code?
i tried using htmlunit, but don't know how to use it properly

Answer (score 0):

The HTML page is being stored in the variable jsp.
alert(jsp) would show you the page.

Comment: `Undefined local method or variable 'alert'` ;)

Comment: So this is not javascript. alert shows you in a popup window what's in a variable.

Comment: I'll put it a little more clearly. I need to get a html file from a url in java, but when i do it, it shows a different source code rather than the actual source code, do you have any idea how to get the actual source code? i tried using htmlunit, but don't know how to use it properly

Answer (score 0):

i would like to see the retrieveContent method's code if it's possible 
and if you are trying to read a url's html content directly then there is a nice example here
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

Comment: I did almost just as given in the example, but the html that i get is not the same as the source code that i get in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

There are many html content scrapping libraries out there which will do the trick , the one which I have used is [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org) , JSOUP says:

> "scrape and parse HTML from a URL, file, or string"

JSOUP might suit your purpose.

Comment: Jsoup is what i'm using, but i need to get the HTML to parse through it. Right now, I do not get the right source code at all, I'm getting a different source code when i use a direct method to get the URL's html source.