# Is it possible to access a servlet deployed on glassfish from a desktop application?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm starting to learn about servlets, I know that if I deploy the servlet on the server then I can access that servlet using a get request via browser. now the question I have is that is it possible to access the same servlet from a java desktop application(Using sockets.)?
here is my client side code:

```
public class SocketClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Socket myClient;
        Scanner reader;

        myClient = new Socket("http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/MyFirstServlet", 8080);
        reader = new Scanner(myClient.getInputStream());
        System.out.println(reader.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you can. But you do not have to open socket. You have to create HTTP connection instead. Take a look on the following discussion for details:

[How do I do a HTTP GET in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485708/how-do-i-do-a-http-get-in-java)

If you need to use other HTTP method google something like: "how to make HTTP METHOD request in java" where METHOD is GET, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS etc.

Comment: thank you it helped, I also used UrlConnection and it was ok, but why using sockets throws exception?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. A browser is just a computer program. It uses sockets to communicate with the server. You could write a program that also used sockets to communicate with the server. Your program would have to use the same communication protocol as the a browser: HTTP.

In fact, writing programs that communicate with an HTTP server is so common that Java provides an API for this (look for questions on SO about [using `java.net.URLConnection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)), and there are application frameworks built on top of those basics to make it even easier (such as [`RestTemplate` of Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html)).