# Execute GET request for REST API call in Java

Tags: java, curl, httpclient, httpurlconnection

I want to call REST API for GET request in Java. I want to send some query parameters with the request. How to do it?
The format of the curl command which I want to request is:

```
curl -G -X GET -H "Accept:application/rdf+xml" --data-urlencode text="Sachin Plays cricket" http://wit.istc.cnr.it/stlab/fred
```

Comment: This have been answered many times before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485708/how-do-i-do-a-http-get-in-java

Comment: Well you could try writing some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use the [jersey client](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html) to a get call

this is an example code:

```
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://"my.server:8080/warAppp").path("restService/endpoint").
                                 queryParam("param1", "myFirstParam").
                                 queryParam("param2",String.valueOf(intValueToConverToString));
String result =webResource.type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE).get(ClientResponse.class).getEntity(String.class);
```