# Extract JavaScript String from HTML page with Java

Tags: javascript, java, object

I want to get the value of a particular Javascript variable hard-coded in a html page. Visit the test-case with the following instructions:

- Go to the website : http://www.headphonezone.in/
- Open console
- Type :  `Shopify.theme`
- Output is : `Object {name: "Retina", id: 8528293, theme_store_id: 601, role: "main"}`
- Type : `Shopify.theme.theme_store_id`
- Output is : **601**

The above response comes from the script given below, which is present in all the Shopify stores.

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
      var Shopify = Shopify || {};
      Shopify.shop = "headphone-zone.myshopify.com";
      Shopify.theme = {"name":"Retina","id":8528293,"theme_store_id":601,"role":"main"};

//]]>
</script>
```

How to write a java code to get the value of `Shopify.theme.theme_store_id` field and store it?

Comment: Java (a server-side compiled language) has nothing to do with JavaScript (script language usually executed client-side). They just have similar-sounding names. You would have to send/receive data between your client (e.g. the browser) and your web server, and serialize/deserialize it.

Comment: Do you want to execute the Javascript code and access Javascript objects? Or just parse the html response and extract the data included within the script tags?

Comment: @EricLeibenguth Any one would work. Finally, I need the value in my java program to run further works. Kindly tell me how can I parse html to get the required data by Java.

Comment: @TedNyberg I do understand the difference. But I am not able to know how I can get the required data and store in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Get the html page as a String (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485708/how-do-i-do-a-http-get-in-java))
- Detect the "Shopify.theme" keyword with a regex:

.

```
String patternString = "Shopify.theme\\s*=\\s*.*theme_store_id\\"\\:(\\d+)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

String themeStoreId;
while (matcher.find()) {
    themeStoreId = matcher.group(1);
}
```

Comment: To clarify - this code is extracting the requested string from the HTML page, but does not care at all that it is "JavaScript" or otherwise interpret it in any way. To OP: tags 'JavaScript' and 'Object' are not needed.

Comment: Thanks, I used `String patternString = "(?i)(Shopify.theme)(.+?)(;)";`  worked well!!