# Apache httpclient GET file from local filesystem?

Tags: java, scala, file, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I somehow always thought that this should be possible:

```
val client = HttpClients.createDefault()
val httpGet = new HttpGet("file:///Users/user01/testfile")
client.execute(httpGet)
```

which throws:

```
client: org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient = org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient@4ba3987b
httpGet: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet = GET file:///Users/user01/testfile HTTP/1.1
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: URI does not specify a valid host name: file:///Users/user01/testfile
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.determineTarget(test_ws.sc0.tmp:90)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(test_ws.sc0.tmp:78)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(test_ws.sc0.tmp:103)
    at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(test_ws.sc0.tmp:6)
```

which kind of makes sense as I am creating an `HttpGet` instance.

Does anybody know how this can be done?

Comment: I would say the **HTTP**client is designed to use the **HTTP** protocol, use other tools for other protocols (file, ftp, ...).

Comment: I am on Mac but the file /Users/user01/testfile does exist.

Comment: Maybe you want to use an URL with file:// [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1485737/4136325)

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Yeah I am just trying to get rid of some http calls to external systems and mock the responses by passing in files instead... i.e. I can only play with the URIs as the https calls are fired from an internal library and I only have access to the configs so can only pass in URIs

Answer (score 4):

HttpClient is, surprisingly enough, is a client side HTTP transport library. It does not support any other transport protocols. Not even local file system. What you probably want is [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/) or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

HttpClient is really only for HTTP, but you can achieve the same with plain Java:

```
try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL("file:///tmp/test.in").openStream());
     FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/test.out"))){
    byte dataBuffer[] = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = in.read(dataBuffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
        fileOutputStream.write(dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
} catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

what about using the built-in `java.net.URL` class? That handles both http and file protocols.

Comment: that doesn't work either... I can see that internally the httpclient is trying to extract the host so maybe after all it's not possible - target = URIUtils.extractHost(requestURI);

Comment: But I am sure I've done this in the past but maybe with some kind of a Spring wrapper:

Comment: this just ran properly for me: 
public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("file:///tmp/foo");
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader((InputStream) url.getContent(), Charset.defaultCharset());
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line;
      StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      while ((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
        strBuilder.append(line);
      }
    System.out.println(strBuilder.toString());
 }