# Bash script to reap wikipedia article and convert it to text file

Tags: java, bash, algorithm

I want to create an algorithm for a bash script or a mini java program that will be able to go online to harvest the Wikipedia article of a query I submit to it, and it will convert it to either text file or PDF or any format readable; from HTML format.

Comment: Use the [API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page). Why scrape HTML when you don't need to?

Comment: How, please kindly explain, I don't even know what an API is.

Comment: I have something for you to reap: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface . Also, this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627594/is-there-a-wikipedia-api

Comment: OK, thanks; now how do I get the API.

Comment: @OlalekanAdebari Boris provided you with a link to the API you can read the documentation there or simply try to search on youtube "How to use WIKI API", you will get plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

this is *web scraping*. you can automate browser actions, there are several libraries for this. in java there is `Jaunt` ( http://jaunt-api.com/jaunt-tutorial.htm ) in python there is `webbrowser`, `Request`, `Beautiful Soup` and `Selenium`  ( https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/ )

In wikipedia there is the `Download as PDF` option on the left side you can automate a browser to click this and download the generated pdf

in the wikipedia source code this is `ElectronPdf` in 
`<li id="coll-create_a_book"><a href="/w/index.php?title=Special:Book&amp;bookcmd=book_creator&amp;referer=Web+scraping">Create a book</a></li><li id="coll-download-as-rdf2latex"><a href="/w/index.php?title=Special:ElectronPdf&amp;page=Web+scraping&amp;action=show-download-screen">Download as PDF</a></li><li id="t-print"><a href="/w/index.php?title=Web_scraping&amp;printable=yes" title="Printable version of this page [p]" accesskey="p">Printable version</a></li>`

if you just want the html of a wikipedia side you can simply HTTP GET as described in [How do I do a HTTP GET in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485708/how-do-i-do-a-http-get-in-java)