# Java Socket HTTP GET request

Tags: java, sockets, http

I'm trying to create a simple Java program that create an HTTP request to a HTTP server hosted locally, by using Socket.

This is my code:

```
try
    {
        //Create Connection
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost",80);
        System.out.println("[CONNECTED]");
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream in   = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());


        String header = "GET / HTTP/1.1\n"
                +"Host:localhost\n\n";
        byte[] byteHeader = header.getBytes();
        out.write(byteHeader,0,header.length());

        String res = "";
        /////////////READ PROCESS/////////////
        byte[] buf = new byte[in.available()];
        in.readFully(buf);
        System.out.println("\t[READ PROCESS]");
        System.out.println("\t\tbuff length->"+buf.length);
        for(byte b : buf)
        {
            res += (char) b;
        }
        System.out.println("\t[/READ PROCESS]");
        /////////////END READ PROCESS/////////////

        System.out.println("[RES]");
        System.out.println(res);
        System.out.println("[CONN CLOSE]");

        in.close();
        out.close();
        s.close();


    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But by when I run it the Server reponse with a '400 Bad request error'.
What is the problem? Maybe some HTTP headers to add but I don't know which one to add.

Comment: Is using sockets mandatory? Java provides other classes which may simplify your life: [How do I do a HTTP GET in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1485708)

Comment: You should use "\r\n" as line separator instead of "\n".

Comment: So many errors, so little time. No `Content-length` header. Wrong line terminator. Classic misuse of `available()`. Wrong order of closes. Why are you trying to write this for yourself when Java already does it for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your request:

```
String header = "GET / HTTP/1.1\n"
             + "Host:localhost\n\n";
```

The line break to be used must be Carriage-Return/Newline, i.e. you should change that to

```
String header = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
             + "Host:localhost\r\n\r\n";
```

Next problem comes when you write the data to the OutputStream:

```
    byte[] byteHeader = header.getBytes();
    out.write(byteHeader,0,header.length());
```

The call of `readBytes` without the specification of a charset uses the system's charset which might be a different than the one that is needed here, better use `getBytes("8859_1")`. When writing to the stream, you use `header.length()` which might be different from the length of the resulting byte-array if the charset being used leads to the conversion of one character into multiple bytes (e.g. with UTF-8 as encoding). Better use `byteHeader.length`.

```
    out.write(byteHeader,0,header.length());

    String res = "";
    /////////////READ PROCESS/////////////
    byte[] buf = new byte[in.available()];
```

After sending the header data you should do a `flush` on the OutputStream to make sure that no internal buffer in the streams being used prevents the data to actually be sent to the server.

`in.available()` only returns the number of bytes you can read from the InputStream without blocking. It's **not** the length of the data being returned from the server. As a simple solution for starters, you can add `Connection: close\r\n` to your header data and simply read the data you're receiving from the server until it closes the connection:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
int read;
while ((read = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
    sb.append(new String(buf, 0, read, "8859_1"));
}
String res = sb.toString();
```

Oh and independent form the topic of doing an HTTP request by your own:

```
    String res = "";
    for(byte b : buf)
    {
        res += (char) b;
    }
```

This is a performance and memory nightmare because Java is actually caching all strings in memory in order to reuse them. So the internal cache gets filled with each result of this concatenation. A response of 100 KB size would mean that at least 5 GB of memory are allocated during that time leading to a lot of garbage collection runs in the process.

Oh, and about the response of the server: This most likely comes from the invalid line breaks being used. The server will regard the whole header including the empty line as a single line and complains about the wrong format of the GET-request due to additional data after the HTTP/1.1.

Comment: 'Java is actually caching all strings in memory in order to reuse them': explain. Justify. Cite.

Answer (score 1):

According to [HTTP 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616):

> HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker for all
> protocol elements except the entity-body [...].

So, you'll need all of your request to be ending with `\r\n`.