# Is there a way to automatically download an HTML file?

Tags: java, html, download

So there is this one website that updates frecuently and I want to make a program to download its html every few minutes, however, a quick google search only shows me about making a file automatically download on a website coded in html. Does anybody know how I could do a program to automatically download the html file that html file?

Answer (score 2):

It's not that easy as it might look, and depends on the website itself.

For example, they might use a lot of JavaScript, like a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), in that case you can not just programmatically download the page without executing the JavaScript and so on.

But if you are lucky enough and you are sure, that the page you want to download is mostly a static HTML you can just download everything by using a GET request call, here is how to do it in Java: [How do I do a HTTP GET in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485708/how-do-i-do-a-http-get-in-java)

Then you save the content in the way you want to, the most simple way is saving it into a file: [How do I create a file and write to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it)

If you are unlucky though, the task you want to do becomes way harder and goes into [Web scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping). Many popular websites protect themselves from that.

Anyway, please clarify if you are on the unlucky path.